# Not able to click (VBA + selenium+Chrome) / FindelementbyId

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on the web using VBA+selenium+Chrome
This is code that i used.

```
Sub Trial()

Dim bot As New WebDriver

bot.Start "chrome", "https://internal site/app"

bot.Get "https://internal site/app"


bot.SendKeys "id"

bot.SendKeys bot.Keys.Tab

bot.SendKeys "password"

bot.SendKeys bot.Keys.Enter


bot.FindElementById("a_200").ClickAndHold

bot.FindElementById("a_203").Click

End sub
```

I wanted to click "a_200" (Menu) and "a_203" (2) which is sub-menu..
Is there any solution or advise? VBA said it cannot find element... Plus, is it possible that id for elements that i want to click changes every time when i open new browser?

Thanks in advance.

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-2"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="63"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-2"><img src="/images/dpwn_logo.gif" alt="" border="0"></td>
<td align="center" valign="top" class="E-S-2"><span class="E-S-3">RCTS 2.32</span></td>
<td align="right" valign="top" class="E-S-2"><img src="/images/DHL_logo_icon.gif" alt="" border="0"></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table><span id="a_171fc"><!-- echopoint.MenuBar -->

<div id="a_183cover" onclick="menuCoverClick();" style="position: absolute; display: none; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-image: url(&quot;/app/img?E_id=EP_POPSMENU_COVER&amp;E_z=m871_0&quot;); background-position: left top; width: 1907px; height: 952px; visibility: visible;"></div>
<table class="E-S-4" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tbody><tr><td><div id="a_195" class="E-S-5" onclick="menuClick('a_195','a_183cover',true);" onmouseover="menuMouseOver('a_195',true,'a_183cover'); setColors('a_195','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="menuMouseOut('a_195'); setColors('a_195','#000000','#ffcc00');" style="background: rgb(255, 204, 0);">Home
</div>
<div id="a_195pop" name="jzeno_menupop" class="E-S-6" style="visibility: hidden;"><div id="a_196" class="E-S-7" onclick="menuClick('a_196','a_183cover',false);" onmouseover="menuMouseOver('a_196',false,'a_183cover'); setColors('a_196','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="menuMouseOut('a_196'); setColors('a_196','#000000','#ffe880');">Parameter
</div>
<div id="a_196pop" name="jzeno_menupop" class="E-S-8" style="visibility: hidden;"><div id="a_197" class="E-S-9" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','1000'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_197','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_197','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_197','#000000','#ffe880');">WareHouse
</div>
</div>
<div id="a_198" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','101'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_198','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_198','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_198','#000000','#ffe880');">Change Password/Profile
</div>
<div id="a_199" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','102'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_199','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_199','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_199','#000000','#ffe880');">Logout
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td><div id="a_200" class="E-S-5" onclick="menuClick('a_200','a_183cover',true);" onmouseover="menuMouseOver('a_200',true,'a_183cover'); setColors('a_200','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="menuMouseOut('a_200'); setColors('a_200','#000000','#ffcc00');" style="background: rgb(255, 204, 0);">Menu
</div>
<div id="a_200pop" name="jzeno_menupop" class="E-S-6" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; display: block; left: 94px; top: 18px;"><div id="a_201" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','110'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_201','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_201','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_201','#000000','#ffe880');" style="background: rgb(255, 232, 128);">1
</div>
<div id="a_202" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','111'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_202','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_202','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_202','#000000','#ffe880');" style="background: rgb(255, 232, 128);">2
</div>
<div id="a_203" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','112'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_203','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_203','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_203','#000000','#ffe880');" style="background: rgb(255, 232, 128);">3
</div>
<div id="a_204" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','113'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_204','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_204','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_204','#000000','#ffe880');">4
</div>
<div id="a_205" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','114'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_205','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_205','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_205','#000000','#ffe880');">5
</div>
<div id="a_206" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','115'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_206','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_206','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_206','#000000','#ffe880');">Genetically Modified
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td><div id="a_207" class="E-S-5" onclick="menuClick('a_207','a_183cover',true);" onmouseover="menuMouseOver('a_207',true,'a_183cover'); setColors('a_207','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="menuMouseOut('a_207'); setColors('a_207','#000000','#ffcc00');" style="background: rgb(255, 204, 0);">6
</div>
<div id="a_207pop" name="jzeno_menupop" class="E-S-6" style="visibility: hidden;"><div id="a_208" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','120'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_208','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_208','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_208','#000000','#ffe880');">Search
</div>
<div id="a_209" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','121'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_209','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_209','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_209','#000000','#ffe880');">On Hold
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td><div id="a_210" class="E-S-5" onclick="menuClick('a_210','a_183cover',true);" onmouseover="menuMouseOver('a_210',true,'a_183cover'); setColors('a_210','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="menuMouseOut('a_210'); setColors('a_210','#000000','#ffcc00');" style="background: rgb(255, 204, 0);">Transport
</div>
<div id="a_210pop" name="jzeno_menupop" class="E-S-6" style="visibility: hidden;"><div id="a_211" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','130'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_211','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_211','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_211','#000000','#ffe880');">List
</div>
<div id="a_212" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','131'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_212','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_212','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_212','#000000','#ffe880');">PDF-RTF link
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td><div id="a_213" class="E-S-5" onclick="menuClick('a_213','a_183cover',true);" onmouseover="menuMouseOver('a_213',true,'a_183cover'); setColors('a_213','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="menuMouseOut('a_213'); setColors('a_213','#000000','#ffcc00');" style="background: rgb(255, 204, 0);">Online Books
</div>
<div id="a_213pop" name="jzeno_menupop" class="E-S-6" style="visibility: hidden;"><div id="a_214" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','140'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_214','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_214','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_214','#000000','#ffe880');">DG Products
</div>
<div id="a_215" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','141'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_215','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_215','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_215','#000000','#ffe880');">Live Animals
</div>
<div id="a_216" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','142'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_216','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_216','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_216','#000000','#ffe880');">Species+
</div>
<div id="a_217" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','143'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_217','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_217','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_217','#000000','#ffe880');">Perishables
</div>
<div id="a_218" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','144'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_218','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_218','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_218','#000000','#ffe880');">User Manual
</div>
<div id="a_219" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','145'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_219','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_219','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_219','#000000','#ffe880');">Admin User Manual
</div>
<div id="a_220" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','146'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_220','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_220','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_220','#000000','#ffe880');">ViewOnly User Manual
</div>
<div id="a_221" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','147'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_221','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_221','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_221','#000000','#ffe880');">FAQ
</div>
<div id="a_222" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','148'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_222','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_222','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_222','#000000','#ffe880');">AAS
</div>
<div id="a_223" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','149'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_223','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_223','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_223','#000000','#ffe880');">RCG E-shop
</div>
<div id="a_224" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','1410'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_224','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_224','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_224','#000000','#ffe880');">RCG Web Page
</div>
<div id="a_225" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','1411'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_225','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_225','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_225','#000000','#ffe880');">Emergency Info
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td><div id="a_226" class="E-S-5" onclick="menuClick('a_226','a_183cover',true);" onmouseover="menuMouseOver('a_226',true,'a_183cover'); setColors('a_226','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="menuMouseOut('a_226'); setColors('a_226','#000000','#ffcc00');">Cognos
</div>
<div id="a_226pop" name="jzeno_menupop" class="E-S-6" style="visibility: hidden;"><div id="a_227" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','150'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_227','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_227','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_227','#000000','#ffe880');">RCTS
</div>
<div id="a_228" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','151'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_228','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_228','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_228','#000000','#ffe880');">Awb History Flow
</div>
<div id="a_229" class="E-S-7" onclick="E_setAction('a_183','152'); closeOpenMenus(); setColors('a_229','#000000','#ffe880');" onmouseover="setColors('a_229','#000000','#eeeeee');" onmouseout="setColors('a_229','#000000','#ffe880');">Uld History Flow
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<!-- End echopoint.MenuBar -->

</span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td class="E-S-10"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-2"><span id="a_19fc"><div id="CMSErrorMessagesFloater" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; margin: 0px; padding: 2px 0px 2px 4px; z-index: 100000; left: 0px; top: 337px; visibility: hidden; width: 1903px;"><table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-1"><span id="a_172fc"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-1"><span id="a_173fc"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-1"><span id="a_174fc"></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-2"><span id="a_25fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-2"><span id="a_175fc"></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-2"><span id="a_28fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td class="E-S-16"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%" height="600"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-11" height="1"><span id="a_176fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><colgroup><col>
<col width="1%">
<col width="1%">
<col width="1%">
<col width="1%">
</colgroup>
<tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-12"><span id="a_239fc"><span id="a_240fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="middle" class="E-S-12"><span id="a_242fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_244fc"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:8pt; cursor: pointer; " onclick="E_setAction('a_244','press')" onkeypress="E_pbkp2(event,'a_244',false);" tabindex="0">Navigation:</span>
</span></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_279fc"><span style="font-family:Arial; font-size:8pt; cursor: pointer; " onclick="E_setAction('a_279','press')" onkeypress="E_pbkp2(event,'a_279',false);" tabindex="0">Welcome</span></span></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_284fc"></span></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_285fc"></span></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_286fc"></span></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_287fc"></span></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_288fc"></span></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_289fc"></span></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_290fc"></span></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_291fc"></span></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_292fc"></span></td>
<td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_293fc"></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span>
</span></td>
<td align="right" valign="middle" class="E-S-12" width="1%"><span id="a_257fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1" height="1"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_294fc"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_295fc"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_296fc"></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span></td>
<td align="right" valign="middle" class="E-S-12" width="1%"><span id="a_272fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1" height="1"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_274fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="1%" height="1"><tbody><tr><td align="center" valign="middle" class="E-S-12"><span id="a_276fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1%"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_278fc"><img src="/images/icons/1410895478_DHL_Shipping.png" alt="" border="0" onmouseover="tooltipHandler(event,'\x3Cdiv\x20style\x3D\x27font\x2Dfamily\x3A\x20Arial\x3B\x20font\x2Dsize\x3A\x2012px\x3B\x20color\x3A\x20\x23000000\x3B\x20background\x2Dcolor\x3A\x20\x23ffffe7\x3B\x20padding\x3A\x202px\x3B\x20border\x2Dstyle\x3A\x20solid\x3B\x20border\x2Dwidth\x3A\x201px\x3B\x20border\x2Dcolor\x3A\x20\x23000000\x3B\x27\x3EWarehouse\x20is\x20clean\x21\x3C\x2Fdiv\x3E'); " onmouseout="disableTooltip(); " style="font-family:Arial; font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold; cursor: pointer; " onclick="E_setAction('a_278','press')" onkeypress="E_pbkp2(event,'a_278',false);" tabindex="0">
</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span></td>
<td align="right" valign="middle" class="E-S-12" width="1%"><span id="a_262fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1" height="1"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_297fc"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_298fc"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_299fc"></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span></td>
<td align="right" valign="middle" class="E-S-12" width="1%"><span id="a_267fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1" height="1"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_300fc"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_301fc"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_280fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="1%" height="1"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_282fc"><img src="/images/icons/syncon.png" alt="" border="0" onmouseover="tooltipHandler(event,'\x3Cdiv\x20style\x3D\x27font\x2Dfamily\x3A\x20Arial\x3B\x20font\x2Dsize\x3A\x2012px\x3B\x20color\x3A\x20\x23000000\x3B\x20background\x2Dcolor\x3A\x20\x23ffffe7\x3B\x20padding\x3A\x202px\x3B\x20border\x2Dstyle\x3A\x20solid\x3B\x20border\x2Dwidth\x3A\x201px\x3B\x20border\x2Dcolor\x3A\x20\x23000000\x3B\x27\x3ESynchronizing\x20MVT\x20messages.\x20Click\x20to\x20stop\x20synchronizing\x20MVT\x20messages.\x3C\x2Fdiv\x3E'); " onmouseout="disableTooltip(); " style="font-family:Arial; font-size:8pt; font-weight:bold; cursor: pointer; " onclick="E_setAction('a_282','press')" onkeypress="E_pbkp2(event,'a_282',false);" tabindex="0">
</span></td>
<td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-13"><span id="a_302fc"></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-11"><span id="a_187fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-1"><span id="a_189fc"><span id="a_190fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-1"><span id="a_192fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td class="E-S-15"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" width="100%"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-14">Welcome</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span>
</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="right" valign="top" class="E-S-2"><span id="a_163fc"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-2"><span id="a_165" class="E-S-17">User : YoungAe LEE (DHL KR) , Gtw : ICN (Alias : SEL)&nbsp; (23.148.59.172)</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="right" valign="top" class="E-S-2"><span id="a_167fc"><span id="a_168" style="cursor: auto; color: #000000; font-size: 6pt; font-family: Arial; ">page served : (UTC) 2020.07.23 AD at 12:55:10</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="left" valign="top" class="E-S-2"><span id="a_170fc"></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Can you share the URL or even the complete HTML?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I attached and full code. This is from internal website for our company so you cannot go to that site...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to someone who was dealing with the a similar kind of menu. Selenium's Actions API might be helpful to you.

You'll want to wait in between clicking and clicking and holding, and use the .Perform function if possible because currently your code doesnt appear to check if the element is clickable ( a big problem for rookie web scrapers )

[Stack Exchange Answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/25063)

Comment: Thank you so much for your advise.  I'll check about API and how to check if the element is clickable or not... i was too excited to find out that i could click google "search button" and thought it can be easily done for company website. I'll check the things you told me!